# HTML object tag - can I specify width and height as percentage?

Tags: html

Does object tag take percentage as valid height and width? I'm looking at [MDN description of object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/object) and it says that height and width are both specified in - `CSS pixels`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [HTML5 draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-dim-width):

> **Author requirements**: The `width` and `height` attributes on `img`, `iframe`, `embed`, `object`, `video`, and, when their `type` attribute
>   is in the Image Button state, `input` elements may be specified to
>   give the dimensions of the visual content of the element (the width
>   and height respectively, relative to the nominal direction of the
>   output medium), in CSS pixels. **The attributes, if specified, must have
>   values that are valid non-negative integers.**

The attributes' values are assumed to be pixels, so there's really no way to provide a percentage.

Answer (score 1):

It's valid to use percentage values for height and width when you are using an HTML 4.01 doctype. It's not valid in HTML5.

Pixel values are valid in HTML5 because it can sometimes be "semantic" to provide the intrinsic dimensions of a resource in the mark-up. But percentage values always imply that the values are presentational, so they are obsoleted in HTML5 and you should use CSS to provide those percentage dimensions instead.

Comment: So I can apply a class with width & height properties equal 100% and it will be okay even in HTML5?

Comment: @dev.e.loper - That's correct. A class, or any other CSS selector binding between your `<object>` element and a CSS rule with height:100% and width:100% is fine in HTML5.